# Postman not working with JWT authentication?

Tags: rest, powershell, authentication, jwt, postman

I'm trying to build a POC for Postman, converting some API tests from Powershell.

Here is one such call:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $getSiteListUri -Headers $headers
```

Headers consists of uuid and Authorization (JWT).

Putting this into Postman with No Auth, and the same headers generates a Success: False response.

Things I've tried:

```
-Adding "Bearer " to Authorization
-Removing no-cache and Postman-Token from the header in settings.
```

What other steps do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I was facing: one personal, the other server related.

First I was manually copying the JWT from powershell output which inserted spaces where new lines occurred. To resolve that, I used:

```
$header.Authorization | clip
```

Second, after checking server logs, there seems to be an inherent problem that regularly occurs. Some calls result in ""Unable to download Json Web Keys from ****". Even in Powershell, this error occurs sometimes. Might be due to hangups on the server, slow responses, heavy load. Will have to check with the teams responsible.